# AWS Amazon ssh keys for instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, vps

I wasn't sure if i should post this on StackOverflow.com or superuser.com, so please forgive me.

I am working for a company whose programmer recently passed away and we have lost our SSH key to our instance on the AWS amazon server.

I have no experience in this type of situation, the information that is on the server is considered sensitive.

I have read that in order to generate a new SSH key for this instance we need to create a new instance and send all the information from that instance to the new instance. is this true? if not what do i need to do exactly?

Also any documentation related to this top is 100% helpful.

Comment: You might get some help browsing http://security.stackexchange.com/ as well. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is EBS-backed, you can stop it and then mount its root volume as a filesystem on a different AWS instance in the same AZ that you have root access to, and use that instance to edit the ssh keys. If you need instructions more detailed than that, then you need to pay someone with decent Unix sysadmin and AWS experience to do it for you.

If the server is instance-store, then you're going to need to raise a support ticket with AWS support. I don't know any way to get into an instance-store instance in the situation that you describe. If it's just the data that you need, and the data is on an EBS volume, then you can mount that volume on a different instance as above.